# Thread 1 SIGABRT in Xcode

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, debugging

This is the message I read when I try to run my application. There are no breakpoints inside of the app that may stop it. I really don't know what to do. Help me please!!

```
2015-12-21 21:31:51.920 Secondo B[11523:709635] Unknown class _TtC9Secondo_B14ViewController in Interface Builder file.
2015-12-21 21:31:51.934 Secondo B[11523:709635] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7a672ed0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key passwordLabel.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x013fca84 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0322de02 objc_exception_throw + 50
2   CoreFoundation                      0x013fc6a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   Foundation                          0x0184e31c -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
4   Foundation                          0x017a88da _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 115
5   Foundation                          0x017a885f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 295
6   UIKit                               0x01f37845 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 85
7   Foundation                          0x017dd0bd -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 384
8   UIKit                               0x021aa05c -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 132
9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0324200c -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0132d571 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 273
11  UIKit                               0x021a86f6 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2102
12  UIKit                               0x01f3f294 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 429
13  UIKit                               0x01f3fccc -[UIViewController loadView] + 189
14  UIKit                               0x01f400d8 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 154
15  UIKit                               0x01f409c5 -[UIViewController view] + 35
16  UIKit                               0x027d7bbc -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 89
17  UIKit                               0x01f0a3e7 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 140
18  UIKit                               0x01f54e4d -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4539
19  UIKit                               0x01f5834b __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 397
20  UIKit                               0x01f58690 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 493
21  UIKit                               0x01f58177 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 182
22  UIKit                               0x0257787f __74-[UIStoryboardPresentationSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 173
23  UIKit                               0x02592c62 -[UIStoryboardSegue perform] + 37
24  UIKit                               0x0257f1e7 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 508
25  UIKit                               0x0257efbf -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 92
26  UIKit                               0x01f4356b -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 105
27  Secondo B                           0x000c4d49 _TFC9Secondo_B18ViewControllerHome13viewDidAppearfS0_FSbT_ + 409
28  Secondo B                           0x000c4dbf _TToFC9Secondo_B18ViewControllerHome13viewDidAppearfS0_FSbT_ + 63
29  UIKit                               0x01f46582 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 774
30  UIKit                               0x01f46d01 -[UIViewController __viewDidAppear:] + 166
31  UIKit                               0x01f85d77 -[UINavigationController viewDidAppear:] + 227
32  UIKit                               0x01f46582 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 774
33  UIKit                               0x01f46d01 -[UIViewController __viewDidAppear:] + 166
34  UIKit                               0x01f497c9 __64-[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]_block_invoke + 57
35  UIKit                               0x01f4778b -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 92
36  UIKit                               0x01d83a6e _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 704
37  UIKit                               0x01d98d81 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 103
38  UIKit                               0x01d98b6d __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 124
39  CoreFoundation                      0x01316d00 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
40  CoreFoundation                      0x0130c683 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
41  CoreFoundation                      0x0130bdb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1016
42  CoreFoundation                      0x0130b706 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
43  CoreFoundation                      0x0130b51b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
44  GraphicsServices                    0x05979664 GSEventRunModal + 192
45  GraphicsServices                    0x059794a1 GSEventRun + 104
46  UIKit                               0x01d761eb UIApplicationMain + 160
47  Secondo B                           0x000c5eec main + 140
48  libdyld.dylib                       0x03c9ba21 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key passwordLabel`. That's the key. Did you check you `passwordLabel` outlet?

Comment: @AlejandroIván sorry, but what do you mean by "passwordLabel"?

Comment: That is what the error message states in the last characters - `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key passwordLabel` - you probably at some time set up some iboutlet and then removed that outlet from the code but not the connection in the IB.

Comment: When you created a label in your Storyboard, you **connected** it with code (Ctrl-Drag) and created an outlet. That outlet doesn't exist anymore, but the Storyboard keeps looking for it and crashes. In this code, that property was called `passwordLabel`.

Comment: I found the error. Thanks a lot for helping me out! @luk2302 and Alejandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the outlet for `passwordLabel`. You can do this through ctr + drag from the label to the IBOutlet. Hope this helps.